# Download audio from YouTube using pytube

Tags: youtube, python-3.5, youtube-data-api, pytube

I'm using pytube and Python 3.5 to download videos from YouTube but I need to convert the videos to audio with an .avi extension.

Here is my code that I'm currently working with:

```
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube(str(input("Enter the video link: ")))
videos = yt.get_videos()

s = 1
for v in videos:
    print(str(s)+". "+str(v))
    s += 1

n = int(input("Enter the number of the video: "))
vid = videos[n-1]

destination = str(input("Enter the destination: "))
vid.download(destination)

print(yt.filename+"\nHas been successfully downloaded")
```

In the code above I can download a video.

My question is: How can I directly download the audio of a video on YouTube with an extension of `.avi`?

Can YouTube Data API help me download exclusively the audio?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: in the code above I can download a video.
my question is how can I directly download the audio of a video on youtube with the extension .avi ?

Comment: There are two issues here. One is that you need to clarify your current question and future questions. Actually asking a question is a good start. I can edit what you just wrote in this time as an example of what one can do. The other issue is that if you want to download audio exclusively from youtube, you would need youtube to supply audio and video data that are encoded separately. That's not impossible -- but it seems unlikely to me. Regardless of what interface you use, it would seem that you have to download the video file with audio and then extract the audio from there

Comment: can Youtube Data API helps me to download exclusively the audio ?

Comment: I don't know. Let's add what you just asked to your original question and also add the relevant tags. Adding the right tags help you attract the attention of those who have experience with the specific topic. But of course, whenever you do add tags, you need to make sure your question is relevant to the tags and vice versa.  In this case, you think it might be. So it's suitable to ask that specifically and then tag away

Comment: yeah ! i understand

Comment: If tags and question don't relate, people may spend time examining your question, find it irrelevant, and recommend deletion. That won't help you solve your problem. Good luck!

Comment: i think i find out the answer from the documentation of pytube library, if you are interested https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/python-pytube/latest/python-pytube.pdf

Comment: Interesting. Indeed, on page 9, it mentions that some streams may have separate codex. It would seem that in such cases, you are able to download the audio separately. If it works for you, maybe answer the question yourself? That way, people in the future can refer to your question/answer and benefit from your knowledge!

Comment: Yes, i did it. It is very simple. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 22):

Upgrade your pytube, as it seems that YouTube().get_videos() is deprecated.
About downloading the video: you can filter the streams for audio with a command like `YouTube().streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()`. Printing that function can guide you to the type of audio you want to download. In order to give it .avi format, I think you can use any converter. I'm using python 3.6.

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt=YouTube(link)
t=yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
t[0].download(/path)
```

Comment: the problem that i found is i named my python file 'pytube.py' which makes python to create a folder called 'pytube_cache'. So, when i rename the file it works very good. Thanks for your help !!

Comment: Can you tell what is the difference between .first() & .all() used after filter?

Comment: The code needs to be adapted to deal with `DeprecationWarning: Call
to deprecated function all (This object can be treated as a list, all() is usele
ss).`. To fix it, remove `.all()`.

Comment: @Gourab the difference is that `.first()` will only retrieve the `first` stream from the list and `.all()` will retrieve every stream. As of today, calling `.all()` is meaningless, as you get the same list of results without calling it.