# How to combine audio and video in Pytube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, pytube, audio-video-sync

I am trying to write a code to download YouTube videos using Pytube on Python 3.6. But for most videos progressive download(Audio and Video in same file) format is available only upto 360p. So I want to download audio and video files separately and combine it. I am able to to download the audio and video files. How can I combine the two file together?

Comment: Can you provide some code examples you already tried? Where specifically is your problem? Your question seem s to be too broad to be answered concisely. (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically I don't find any method to marge Audio and Video in `Pytube` but you can use `ffmpeg` for muxing.

First of all you have to install `ffmpeg`

1. > `ffmpeg` installation guide for [Windows](https://m.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows)
2. > for `Ubuntu` just `sudo apt install ffmpeg`

Add a dependency `ffmpeg-python` a python wrapper of `ffmpeg`

3. > `pip install ffmpeg-python`

Now we are ready to go with this code snippet

```
import ffmpeg

video_stream = ffmpeg.input('Of Monsters and Men - Wild Roses.mp4')
audio_stream = ffmpeg.input('Of Monsters and Men - Wild Roses_audio.mp4')
ffmpeg.output(audio_stream, video_stream, 'out.mp4').run()
```

for more, `ffmpeg-python` [API References](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/)

Answer (score 5):

If you keep getting a video without audio, that's because of the adaptive streaming from pytube. A work-around is to download both video and audio... then merge them with ffpmeg.

For instance, something like this to get both audio and video (audio part adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041191/5675325))

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

youtube = YouTube('https://youtu.be/ksu-zTG9HHg')
video = youtube.streams.filter(res="1080p").first().download()
os.rename(video,"video_1080.mp4")
audio = youtube.streams.filter(only_audio=True)
audio[0].download()
```

and then the ffmpeg part (adapted from both [here](https://superuser.com/a/277667/706430) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744932/5675325)) you can set it up on Windows following [this procedure](https://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows) and then run something like

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

**Merging audio and video using ffmpeg**

Once you have downloaded both video and audio files (‘videoplayback.mp4’ and ‘videoplayback.m4a’ respectively), here’s how you can merge them into a single file:

**In case of MP4 format (all, except 1440p 60fps & 2160p 60fps):**

```
ffmpeg -i videoplayback.mp4 -i videoplayback.m4a -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4
```

**In case of WebM format (1440p 60fps and 2160p 60fps):**

```
ffmpeg -i videoplayback.webm -i videoplayback.m4a -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mkv
```

Wait until ffmpeg finishes merging audio and video into a single file named "output.mp4".

Answer (score 1):

**How do I convert the downloaded audio file to mp3?**

you need to execute the following command in the Command Prompt window:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_FILE -ab BITRATE -vn OUTPUT_FILE
```

**Example:**

```
ffmpeg -i videoplayback.m4a -ab 128000 -vn music.mp3
```

**Example:2** (without bit rate)

```
ffmpeg -i videoplayback.m4a -vn music.mp3
```

Comment: Please avoid asking queastions in answers, even if the quote the question post or are rhetorical. You risk being misread as asking a question instead of answering, i.e. of havin your question flagged as not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `moviepy` to merge

```py
from pytube import YouTube
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, AudioFileClip, concatenate_videoclips

# download video and audio
yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxx')
yt.streams.get_by_itag(135).download(filename="video.mp4")
yt.streams.get_by_itag(140).download(filename="audio.mp4")

# combine the video clip with the audio clip
video_clip = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")
audio_clip = AudioFileClip("audio.mp4")
final_clip = video_clip.set_audio(audio_clip)
final_clip.write_videofile("filename" + ".mp4")
```