# Pytube not all available video qualities are showing | Python 3.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, pytube

I'm programming a youtube video downloader that allows you to download youtube videos in different resolutions and refresh rates. However, when I try to list the available resolutions and fps, I weirdly only get lower quality options. In my code example I am using the [YouTube Rewind 2019 video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo) that is used for an example in the [docs](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#dash-vs-progressive-streams). Here is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

youtube = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo')

for stream in youtube.streams.filter(progressive=True):
    print("resolution: " + stream.resolution)
    print("fps: " + str(stream.fps))
    print("----------------------")
```

and here is my output:

```
/mnt/d/youtube-downloader$ python3 main.py
resolution: 360p
fps: 24
----------------------
resolution: 720p
fps: 24
----------------------
```

As you can see the only qualities I get are 720p and 360p although the youtube video used can scale all the way up to 1080p. Is there a different function I should be aware of.

I've also found a closed [GitHub issue](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/106) which seems to be similar to mine but doesn't have an answer I can work with which is why I've posted this issue here.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've just gone through the same issue. You can use something like this

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

youtube = YouTube('https://youtu.be/kdmgpMfnjdU')
video = youtube.streams.filter(res="480p").first().download()
os.rename(video,"video_best.mp4")
```

Notice that 480p is the best available quality in that video.

*Note*: if you keep getting a video without audio, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67595216/5675325) on how to tackle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download it in lowest or highest quality by--

highest-

```
youtube.streams.get_highest_resolution.download()
```

lowest-

```
youtube.streams.get_lowest_resolution.download()
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all available resolutions in a video, you can use the `adaptive` filter.

```py
video = youtube("URL")
resolution = video.streams.filter(adaptive=true)
```

`progressive=true` allows you to view only progressive downloads. A progressive download is a legacy stream containing the audio and video in a single file, available for resolutions 720 and below.

Answer (score 0):

Because "progressive=True" in

```py
for stream in youtube.streams.filter(progressive=True)
```

The highest quality you can get is 720p and below when "progressive=True", read this [section](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/streams.html#dash-vs-progressive-streams) on pytube docs it explains it all.

If u want the highest avaliable quality with the best audio u can do this by downloading the two files then merging them using ffmpeg.